# My wifi disconnects and has trouble reconnecting (Mi wifi de desconecta y le cuesta conectarse otra vez)

Tags: drivers, wireless, internet, realtek

Uso Ubuntu studio 23 lunar booster
Con el comando `inxi -Fxz` me da esto

```
Network:
  Device-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet
    vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: r8169 v: kernel port: f000 bus-ID: 01:00.0
  IF: eno1 state: down mac: <filter>
  Device-2: Realtek RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
    vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: rtw_8821ce v: N/A port: e000 bus-ID: 02:00.0
  IF: wlp2s0 state: up mac: <filter>
```

También me da el error al intentar conectarse de:

```
error Interfaz inalámbrica (wlp2s0) : No se ha proporcionado ninguna credencial
```

Alguien ha enfrentado lo mismo y lo ha solucionado de alguna manera?.
Gracias...

#### Translation

I am using Ubuntu studio 23 Lunar booster. When I run the command `inxi -Fxz`, it gives me this:

```
Network:
  Device-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet
    vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: r8169 v: kernel port: f000 bus-ID: 01:00.0
  IF: eno1 state: down mac: <filter>
  Device-2: Realtek RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
    vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: rtw_8821ce v: N/A port: e000 bus-ID: 02:00.0
  IF: wlp2s0 state: up mac: <filter>
```

I also get the error when trying to connect:

```
Wireless interface error (wlp2s0): No credential provided
```

Has anyone had this same problem and solved it somehow? Thank you...

Comment: Your question isn't clear to me, as you sure you translated it into english?  This is an english only site; non-english support is provided elsewhere.

Comment: Firefox has a translate function built-in, so you may edit your own question to translate it to english.